# Upgrading from .net 6 to .net 7 database connection issues

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-6.0, .net-7.0

I've been upgrading an application from .net6 to .net 7 and I cannot connect to the database.

below is the connection string

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=.\\MYINSTANCE;Database=MyDatabase;User Id=MyUser; Password=MyPassoword;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"
  }
```

And the connection

```
var connectionString = _configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
connection.Open();
```

Which works great in dotnet 6, however once i update to 7 it stops giving me the following error.

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A connection was
> successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred
> during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The
> certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.)
> ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80090325): The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.

Does anyone have any ideas on this or why this is happing?

Comment: [Encrypt defaults to true for SQL Server connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/breaking-changes#encrypt-true)

Comment: If I had to take a guess, I'd say it's because "The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted". When faced with such a message, you should look up how to verify the certificate used by SQL Server, and how to obtain a valid certificate.